# Integrator not properly loading in Hibernate 5.x

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I'm working with Hibernate 5 in a web project, and I need to listen to some database events such as updates and deletes.

I'm trying to use the event structure from Hibernate, and I need to use an Integrator to add my listeners. The problem is, the way most guides are using to do it (creating a file META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator with the full name of my Integrator class) is not working for me at all. I've tried debugging the ClassLoaderService, and my integrator is just ignored.

Has anyone gone to this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, while using the `EventListenerRegistry` with a custom Integrator approach of intercepting events:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-events.

I couldn't get my events (eg `EventType.PRE_INSERT`, `EventType.PRE_UPDATE`) to work when I called `session.save(entity)` or `session.update(entity)`.

When I switched to `EventType.PERSIST` and used `session.persist(entity)`, things started working.